# simulate selection in windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have this in my Notepad:

```
hello
```

I want to simulate selecting in C++ using Windows' `keybd_event` function.
here is my code:

```cpp
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

but after I run this, it didn't select anything, it just go to the start of the file. Why isn't this working?

Comment: You could use UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 with the selection pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementingselection instead of messing up with the keyboard

Comment: but is there a way I can use  `<Windows.h>` only?

Comment: Yes you can send the `EM_SETSEL` message to the edit control in the notepad window.

Comment: What's the specific requirement you have that allows you to `#include <Windows.h>` but not any other header file provided by the Windows SDK? Also note that for the presented approach to work (which, [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event), cannot work reliably anyway) the target window has to be the foreground window. A requirement that does not exist when using UI Automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY will select rightly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-keybdinput#members

```
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
Sleep(2000);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    Sleep(20);
}
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

Use VK_SHIFT in keybd_event, There is a problem that shift cannot be released，I recommend you use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead of keybd_event.
For higher-level operations, I also recommend you use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Comment: even though it did manage to select the text, I can't make it stop selecting. This function isn't working
`keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, 0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);`

Comment: I mentioned this issue in my answer

Comment: right, sorry. It works. Thanks alot!